# Disable browser specific hotkeys for Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have Silverlight application implemented using MVVM architecture.

Now I want to use browser specific shortcuts (Hotkeys) in my application. Is there any way to disable/edit browser specific (all browsers) shortcuts like CTRL + P, CTRL + S etc.?

I do not want to use java script.

Please help..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. It's raised in full-screen mode or out-of-browser but with limitation too... You can use shortcuts like `CTRL+SHIFT+S` but it is not user-friendly ..

MSDN Doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189015(VS.95).aspx#Keyboard_Events

> If an application is browser-hosted, the browser host determines which
>   keystrokes it interprets as commands and which keystrokes it passes on
>   to hosted content. This means that certain keystroke combinations
>   cannot be retrieved from KeyDown and KeyUp event handler functions in
>   some set of browser hosts. Most keystrokes that a browser hosts
>   interprets as commands are shortcut or accelerator keystrokes, and
>   when this happens the keystrokes are not passed as key events to
>   Silverlight. For example, CTRL+D is a shortcut keystroke combination
>   for adding a favorite URL to the Firefox and Internet Explorer browser
>   hosts, and neither CTRL nor D is reported as a key event to the
>   intermediate hosting layer that Silverlight must use as its input
>   source when Silverlight-based applications are hosted by a browser.